How to build a ROS2 node in C++ AND Python using ament_cmake only
I'm fairly new to ROS development and currently got the task to translate a py node to cpp. The py node was proof of concept while the cpp node should be the final one. For now they should be in the same package though, which is why I'm looking for a build where I select the implementation in a config file, which is then evaluated by the launch.py to load the chosen implementation. However for now I don't get the build running flaweless with cmake. The build works, but when running the node it crashes in the load_entry_point.
I tried orientating at some guides, e.g. from Robotics Back-End but didn't get it running yet.
I got the following dependencies in my package.xml:
  <depend>rclcpp</depend>
  <depend>rclpy</depend>
  <depend>ros2launch</depend>

  <test_depend>ament_copyright</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_flake8</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_pep257</test_depend>
  <test_depend>python3-pytest</test_depend>

  <test_depend>ament_lint_auto</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_lint_common</test_depend>
  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>
  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake_python</buildtool_depend>

  <export>
    <!--build_type>ament_python</build_type-->
    <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
  </export>

and this is my CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25.2)
project(package)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD 20)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

if (POLICY CMP0167)
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0167 NEW)
endif()

find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(ament_cmake_python REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(rclpy REQUIRED)

find_package(Torch REQUIRED)
find_package(xtensor REQUIRED)
find_package(cudnn_cmake_module REQUIRED)
find_package(tensorrt_cmake_module REQUIRED)

find_package(lanelet2_core REQUIRED)
find_package(lanelet2_extension REQUIRED)

include_directories("/usr/include")
link_directories("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")

include_directories(include)
include_directories(${TORCH_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${xtensor_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(node_cpp 
  src/node.cpp 
)

ament_target_dependencies(node_cpp 
  rclcpp 
  rclpy
  geometry_msgs
  lanelet2_core
  lanelet2_extension
)

target_link_libraries(node_cpp 
  yaml-cpp 
  ${rclcpp_LIBRARIES} 
  Eigen3::Eigen 
  ${TORCH_LIBRARIES} 
  xtensor 
  nvinfer 
  nvinfer_plugin
  nvonnxparser
)


set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${TORCH_CXX_FLAGS})

install(TARGETS node_cpp DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME})

ament_python_install_package(${PROJECT_NAME})
install(PROGRAMS package/node.py DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME})


ament_package()

As you can notice, I still have the ament_python in my package.xml as building once with it first and then building with ament_cmake works. However I think there should be a solution where just a cmake build is sufficient, no? Building twice seems not correct to me at least.
What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

I don't have an answer, but I'd like to challenge the question: why insist to combine your Python and C++ code in one package? It seems a waste of time to try and solve this issue, while you can easily source two separate packages in a workspace?

Because I'm working within the existing package. And given the examples I assumed fixing the build would be easier then refactoring my workspace.

There might not be a need for refactoring. I think it could be just a matter of adding a new package with your new code, launching those nodes instead (with the same names) and the rest should remain identical (except your launch files). It doesn't even need to be in the same workspace. You just need to source it.
